# How to get indexPath of a custom cell in PrepareForSegue method - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue, nsindexpath

I have a custom `cell` with few views and buttons in it. From 1 of the buttons, I'm performing a `Segue` and I need that cell number but no idea how to get it. Please help.

Heres how my cell looks:

[image]

the `prepareForSegue` is called from the red circled button.

Here's the code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return _array.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NewsFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsFeedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell) {
        cell.item = _array[indexPath.section];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AudioComment"])
    {
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.section); //printing 0 everytime :(
    }
}
```

Please provide any help/suggestions on how can i get the `indexPath`?

Thanks.

Comment: Would UITableView's `indexPathForSelectedRow` not do the trick? (docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1615000-indexpathforselectedrow))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set tag on the button. In your case, set the button tag as indexPath.section in CellforRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NewsFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsFeedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell) {
        cell.item = _array[indexPath.section];
    }

    cell.button1.tag = indexPath.section;
    return cell;
}
```

In PrepareForSegue, get the index from button tag.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AudioComment"])
    {
        NSInteger index = ((UIButton *) sender).tag;
        NSLog(@" %ld ",index);
    }
}
```

Comment: A better solution than Hardik  Shekat's :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview]superview];
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[_generalTableView indexPathForCell:cell].row);
```

Comment: This won't work, since the cell is not selected if you click on a UIButton in the table cell.

Comment: `sender.superview.superview` line gives error : "property 'superview' not found on object type '__strong id'"

Comment: @SHA could you try maybe once more ?

Comment: @Misha Just tried with your updated code, still giving 0 at every cell's button tap.

Comment: can you log cell and its contents ? it's working fine my side. You are replacing your cell with UITableViewCell ? and button is in every cell ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable for the index and set it when selecting the cell. Access the variable in perpareForSegue, pass it to the destinationVC and 0 it.

Comment: I'm not selecting a cell, as `didSelectRowAtIndex` never gets called, because I tap a specific button in that cell. How can I get the index

Answer (score 1):

Use below code. It may help you.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MainPhotoCell *cell = (MainPhotoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifierMedia" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[MainPhotoCell alloc] init];
    }
   cell.usrCommentBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
   [cell.usrCommentBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onCommentClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (void)onCommentClick:(id)sender
{
   if ([GlobalManager checkUserLoginStatus:self])
   {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([sender tag]) inSection:0];

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showComments" sender:indexPath];
   }
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"showComments"])
    {
        NSIndexPath * path = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
        //do the your required code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working :( `onCommentClick` never gets called, direct `prepareForSegue` being called.

Comment: Dont do this "[cell.usrCommentBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(onCommentClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];" - use prototype cells with IBActions and delegates from the cell to the VC

Comment: Sure, any code can work, but doesnt mean its good. That way breaks OO design principles.

Comment: @Helium3.  Thanks for your suggestion. I will remind it next time.

Comment: @HardikShekhat do i need to disconnect the `segue` also from that button in storyboard?

Comment: @SHA is "+" button is part of custom cell or not?

Comment: @HardikShekhat Yes it is. and that '+' button is connected via a `segue` to another VC in Storyboard, so when it is tapped, `prepareForSegue` gets called in the `tableViewControllerClass`. 

although your code seems to be correct, but the `onCommentClick` is not getting hit, instead `prepareForSegue` gets called directly.

Comment: @SHA ok then IBOutlet "+" button and give tag and set selector on that in cellForRowAtIndexPath( ) method like i have posted in code.

Comment: @SHA. you have to set selector of button in cellForRowAtIndexPath() then onCommentClick() is getting hit,

Comment: @HardikShekhat Thanks for the guidance. it worked! :D